# How do you call the species that gives its name to a upper-level clade?

Tags: phylogenetics, nomenclature

Just a silly question: I don't remember how the species giving its name to an upper-level clade is called.

e.g. the name of family Canidae derives from *Canis lupus*

You could say it is the "name-giving" species, but I'm certain a specific term exists.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the [type species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_species).
Although it is defined to be a "name giver" for the genus or subgenus level you could potentially extend this to higher up levels.

EDIT: After looking this up and actually reading the full article myself, yes, at least in zoology you can extend it to higher levels by for example using the [type genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_genus).

Comment: Hmm... Thank you
I guess "type genus" is closer to what I was looking for, since it concerns supra-generic clades.
Although I recall once using a term of somewhat greek origin, like blahblah-nymic... but I don't recall what it was...
Maybe "hyponymic species"?